# Auto-refreshing of a portlet after another portlet finished its work

Tags: refresh, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I have two portlets:

1. One is for displaying a list of files (and more)
2. The second is to import files into Liferay's document library.

If I have both portlets on one page how can I achieve that the 'listing' portlet refreshes after the import portlet has finished its work? This is mandatory because the hyperlinks in the listing portlet will change after the import.

Comment: If importing files into document library is done in one portlet action request, then the portal assures reloading of all the portlets on the same page because render phases of all portlets are called after action phase of a single portlet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pointer on how to refresh a portlet using ajax call.

`Liferay.Portlet.refresh("p_p_id_<targetportletnamespae>_");`

Its upto you to decide when to call this js method, based on your requirement.